# Use pyserial in azure edge python module

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to achieve serial communication from the docker while using azure edge python module, it seems pyserial does not work. it's unable to find the physical device port from the docker.

```
{
          "TestPythonModule": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.TestPythonModule}",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "Devices": [
                    {
                      "PathOnHost": "/dev/ttyS0",
                      "PathInContainer": "/dev/ttyS0",
                      "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
                    }
                  ]
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think serial ports are exposed by default to Docker images. That is a Docker configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you mapped the serial port into the container via it's create options in your module configuration...  something like this:

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "<device name on host machine>",
        "PathInContainer": "<device name in container>",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

where device name on host machine is something like /dev/ttys0 or whatever the serial port maps to on your machine?   (I'm assuming Linux)

Comment: it worked, but how to get the serial exception when the USB is getting disconnected? the way we get in pyserial !

Comment: Hey @ArnabGhosh -- unfortunately, I'm not sure as I haven't tried that

Comment: Yes the problem I have faced, when the physical USB is disconnected, then we need to kill the process that is using the serial port ( suppose /dev/ttyACM0), otherwise when we will reconnect the USB device it will take some other USB port as the one it was using is already in use. in that case, reading /writing will be failed !! is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: So ignoring IoT Edge and docker for the moment, how would you solve that normally?

Comment: Normally we get Serial disconnect exception while using pyserial in normal python ! then just dispose of the serial port ! and search for the new one, I solve it like this! but this approach is not gonna work, as docker will still use the old port and the disconnected device will connect to a new port. the same needs to be updated in the desired properties also.

Comment: so if a USB device first maps to /dev/ttyUSB0, if you disconnect it and later reconnect it, it will map to /dev/ttyUSB1 (or something like that?).   ttyUSB0 doesn't get re-used?    (not a USB/serial expert, so trying to understand the behavior)